# Is "Decorators are a proposal" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context, grammatical-number

> [**Decorators are a proposal** for extending JavaScript classes which is widely adopted among developers in transpiler environments, with broad interest in standardization.](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators#decorators)

Is "Decorators are a proposal" grammatically correct?

Or should it be "Decorators is a proposal"?

Comment: Structurally it seems fine, but it doesn't make any sense to me. I don't know what you're trying to say, so I can't tell you a better way to say it. Questions like this are off-topic here anyway as they are considered proof-reading. There is no question about learning English here.

Comment: 'Decorators (_plural_) **are**'..., or 'the use (_singular_) of decorators' **is**... or 'using decorators **is**...'

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thanks for helping out, but is _"Decorators are a proposal"_ grammatically correct?" I know _"Decorators (plural) are"_ is correct.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Good that you recognised the context - BUT that makes this *jargon*, and jargon does not always obey the rules of English grammar. The danger of answering questions like that here is that future readers of the site who are English learners but not computer programmers may also not recognise the context and be completely misled by it.

Comment: Wenfang Du - why are you questioning the contents of a Github `readme.md`? Is the reason curiosity? It's not an academic English-language document.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Simply because I felt the expression _"Decorators are a proposal"_ is odd, and want to verify if it's odd for native speakers.

Comment: This seems like an opinion-based questions. It's a fairly common thing to do, to use "decorators" instead of "the idea of decorators" or "using decorators" (both of which are unambiguously singular). You can consider it a form of ellipsis, in which case it's grammatical. Whether it sounds odd or natural is another question: it might be considered quirky or awkward in some situations.

Comment: The precise answer will depend on whether your question is "does this make sense (and if so, what does it mean)?" or "is this a construction I should use regularly in my own writing?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Decorators are a proposal" is grammatically correct, ["because English is strongly Subject-Verb-Object, with "be", the element before the verb is usually treated as the subject and so this is what the verb agrees with."](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/17219/399139)